# ) expected before ; token in if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I've defined a constant in the header file

```
#define kPortraitMode 1
#define kLandscapeMode 2

Byte:viewOrientation;//this is my ivar that'll keep interface orientation info
```

In willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:withDuration: method i say:

```
if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
   self.viewOrientation=kPortraitMode;
}
else{
    self.viewOrientation=kLandscapeMode;
```

Then in Table View Data source method tableview:height:forIndexPath method I say:

```
double height;
if (self.viewOrientation==kPortraitMode){//Here I get the error) expected before token;

height=263.0;
}
else{
height=320;
}
return height;
```

My question is what am I doing wrong here to get this compiler error? It's just a simple expression.

Comment: Probably not your real problem, but in the second snippet, there seems to be a missing trailing `}`.

Comment: The second code snip is another scope I mean it another method. The error line shows exactly the line I'v show above.But if I don't use that constant that works. Is there a special case with constatnts?

Comment: @mu_is_too short Do you mean If I put a semimcolon after the constant definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sure that the constant defined are like this

```
#define kPortraitMode 1
#define kLandscapeMode 2
```

And not like this:

```
#define kPortraitMode 1;
#define kLandscapeMode 2;
```

The error in the line comes because you have a misplaced statement terminator `;` before closing the `if` condition. So if you have `;` in the constants defined, that may be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your real code, do you happen to have a semicolon after the `#define kPortraitMode`? Putting a ; after a #define is a common mistake.

Also, the `Byte:viewOrientation;` line looks fishy.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of errors in your code.

First of all, you are defining kPortraitMode and kLandscapeMode, when UIInterfaceOrientation(Portrait, LandscapeLeft, LandscapeRight and PortraitUpsideDown) are part of an enum, so that's unnecessary.

Related to that first point. You are assuming everything other than UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait is landscape, which is not true, because there's UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, although if you don't allow upside down orientation, it should be fine. Still, bad practice.

Second, you are creating your own ivar for viewOrientation, when UIViewController already has the property interfaceOrientation, so that's extra memory you are wasting, as well as processing time, by assigning the orientation when it rotates in willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:withDuration:.

And finally, when using enums, imo it's better using switch than using if; you write less comparison code, and it's more clear.

This is how I'd do it:

```
double height = 0.0;
switch(self.interfaceOrientation){
  case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
  case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
    height = 263.0;
    break;
  case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
  case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
    height = 320;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Emilio for deep explanation.Is it still a bad practice if I don't let for upside down and If i don't care landscape right or lef? I really did want to find UIViewController's property that keeps its orientation but somehow I could not find it.But now I see I should've looked it in self not in self.view.

Comment: You should always try to make your code as fool-proof as possible, avoid leaving any kind of vague instructions, it will make it a lot easier to debug, update, and understand.